# How to restart a Node.js project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, service

I'm not a Node.js developer. So I have no idea how it works. I've been a PHP developer for over 8 years.

Because of some reason, I need to make a small change in a Node.js project which is live. All I have to do is changing a payment gateway token. I did it like this:

[image]

After pulling it on the server, **users still go to the old payment gateway**. So I guess I need to do a restart. (I'm saying so because, for PHP projects, when you change a config-related thing, you need to restart PHP).

Not sure should I restart what thing? Noted that, the server is Ubuntu 20.04 and uses Nginx to talk to Node.js. In other word, how can I see Node is running as what service on Linux?

---

Also, there are two files that I think I need to run the project again after restarting Node through one of them: `index.js`, `server.js`. Am I right?

[image]

And

[image]

Comment: How did you _start_ it in the first place?

Comment: @tkausl I just joined to the project few days ago. The old developer has left the team. And I'm going to rewrite the whole project with PHP. Just I need to make that small change in the current running project

Comment: But someone has to manage the application, right? How to _restart_ it depends entirely on how it was started, there are thousands of ways, thats the problem.

Comment: Oh @tkausl ... I see .. And too bad :-(

Comment: Rewriting a project just because someone left the team seems a little... drastic?

Comment: @Andy No buddy, we want to rewrite it because of other reasons. Not just because of that guy

Comment: Ok could you please at least tell me when I modify `/project/utils/zarinpal/appConfig.js` file, do I need to restart the node? or nginx? or no need to restart anything and the changes must be effected without restarting? @tkausl

Comment: You very likely have to restart it

Comment: @tkausl Does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1wVT.png) give you any clue how has it been run in the first place?

Comment: Seems like there are multiple node processes running. Which one of these runs your application (compare the paths)? You have to "walk up" the process tree to figure out who initially started the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Node.js script likely runs under a process that restarts the script in case it dies. There are several "run forever" wrappers, the most popular one is [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/). Find out which one is used in your project. Try `pm2 list` as the user your project executes under. If `pm2` type `pm2 restart app_name` to restart your project.

Comment: Yes thanks, I run `pm2 list` and I saw somethings .. I will work on it. Thanks for the clue

Answer (score 0):

Please check if it is a node.js project so you can write the command `node index.js` or `node server.js` with this command you can start your node server.

Comment: I'm trying to restart a Node server that I had to stop. I searched for `server.js` but couldn't find any. I then searched for `index.js`. That resulted in a LOT of `index.js` in several subdirectories. What subdirectories should I use?